# Is there a better way to save streamed files with MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, streaming, save, media-player

I'm trying to build a mediaplayer app, that allows the user to stream mp3 files from online, and save the file when it's finished downloading.

It looks like MediaPlayer doesn't provide any means of doing this, so existing solutions are a little hacky, and do things like downloading to a separate buffer, and repeatedly stopping/starting the MediaPlayer on buffer updates. As far as I can see, this means small pauses in the audio every time the buffer's swapped, which isn't very good.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do it?

Comment: Will your app work with Icecast streams at all or will it just play mp3 files off of an online site?

Comment: No, just vanilla mp3s. I found a rather discouraging blog post actually, from one of the grooveshark devs: [link](http://pixxid.com/annoyances-with-android-mediaplayer-part-1/2010/06/21/)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the NPR android app, http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/ ? They use a proxy server to stream icecast streams. Now, I know you're looking for plain vanilla mp3s but you should be able to apply the same concept. In fact, it's quite similar to the solution you mentioned in your post, but implementation wise, it doesn't have the audio pauses.

Comment: @Windsurfer - Yeah, that seems like the best solution I think.   
However, I can't really make sense of what's going on in the icecast NPR code. It seems like it could be really simple - something like [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm), but with an additional step in which the downloaded data is written to file? The only problem I can see is it depends on how MediaPlayer's internal buffering works: I'm guessing it doesn't download the file linearly?

Comment: Yea, there's a lot going on, but luckily not all of it has to do with the mediaplayer portion. The jist of it is in StreamProxy.java and PlayBackService.java (revision 121 line 294). The proxy server actually streams the data to a buffer first before feeding it to the mediaplayer. You can see this in StreamProxy.java (revision 121 in processRequest routine). Getting to your question, it actually downloads sequentially, so if you save the data as it comes off the server you will be able to save it. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah ok, that's good news. I'll fix the rest of the app first then, and add this feature later at a later stage. Thanks very much for the help.