# Audio Streaming on Android

Tags: android

I'm attempting to stream from a URL using Android's built in MediaPlayer class.  However, I also need to send a special header along with the URL.  Is this possible without having to rewrite the whole steaming process?

If it's not possible to send a header, I would need to stream the file manually. However, it appears that the MediaPlayer class locks the file you are writing to when it begins reading the file.  This means you cant just simply continue writing to the file while reading from it.  I've seen the 'double buffer' method however that results in choppy playback.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question recently about alternatives to the double buffer method you mentioned:
[is-there-a-better-way-to-save-streamed-files-with-mediaplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460767/is-there-a-better-way-to-save-streamed-files-with-mediaplayer)

Comment: Thanks, I also saw the NPR method but was hoping I wouldnt have to implement it that way.  However, it looks like that may be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could act as a proxy in a thread, handle your header and forward the rest to the media player? Or if you control the server pass the extra data in a different request...

Comment: Any hints on how I would go about doing that?  I tried doing something similar with the NPR code that's out there however I'm ending up with a 'Broken Pipe' error every time I try.